# Handling Exceptions

Tags: java, exception

I have a question regarding this code, it pertains to exceptions:

```
public class MTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            m1();
            m2();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            System.out.println("e");
        }
    }

    static void m1() throws Exception {
        try {
            throw new Exception();
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            System.out.println("m1catch");
        }
    }

    static void m2() throws Exception {
        try {
            throw new Exception();
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Finally");
        }       
    }
}
```

So according to the above code, the textbooks tells me that `m2()` method doesn't handle its own exception, and it's passed to main. What does it mean? And how can I tell from the code above? Does `m1()` handle its own exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any checked exception that can be thrown inside a method must be either be handled in a try/catch block or the method must be declared to throw that exception.  The Java compiler will complain when you try to compile code that breaks these rules.

`m1()` catches the only checked exception, so it handles its own exceptions.  If you remove `throws Exception` from `m1()`'s declaration, it'll compile correctly which implies that it does handle all its checked exceptions.

`m2()` does not handle its exception.  If you remove `throws Exception` from `m2()`'s declaration, you'll get a compile error because there is an exception thrown but not caught or checked.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, m1 will handle it's own exception while m2 will pass or 'throw' the exception up to main. This is because of the catch statement you have in the m1 function. Basically, any exception thrown from the try block will first search if this exception is handled as part of the try (in your code):

`catch (Exception e2){
System.out.println("m1catch");
}`

If there is no catch block, as in m2, the function will then assume the exception is handled higher up, perhaps by a function that called m2. Because main() called m2 this, it is the immediate next place to look, and there the catch block will handle the exception.

Answer (score 0):

`m1()` handles the exception by using `try{}` and `catch`. the thrown exception is caught in the ***catch block()***.

Even if throws Exception is removed, the compiler will not throw any exception.

`m2()` does not catch the exception. only the `try{}` block is used to throw the exception. The exception is not handled within the method. It is set to throw to the main method. Only in the main method, the exception is caught. if throws Exception is removed from `m2()`, the compiler will throw "unreported exception;must be caught or declared to be thrown"